# indefinite Integral of composite function with large power

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to find the indefinite integral of $x\times(5 x - 1)^{19}$ by substitution

So far I have made $u = 5x-1$

so $\frac{du}{dx}=5$ ,  thus $dx = \frac{du}{5}$

I cant seem to find a way to cancel out the $x$ in front! Please help!

Comment: Solve $u=5x-1$ for $x$.

Answer (score 2):

To complete that substitution, write $u = 5x - 1$ so thgat $u + 1 = 5x$ and hence
$$
x = \frac{u+1}{5}
$$
That gives you 
$$
\int x (5x-1)^{19} ~dx = \int \left(\frac{u+1}{5}\right) u^{19} \frac{1}{5} du =\frac{1}{25} \int (u+1) u ^{19} du.
$$